# pepper robots related

Tags: robotics, pepper, choregraphe

So I will be working with pepper robots very soon, but have still lots of questions that am not getting straight answers to so I would really appreciate the help.

1. Does pepper need continuous internet connection for all activities. Say I was doing to do a demo somewhere do I need internet for that as well.
2. What security features can be embedded to the robot itself by me.
3. Does the robot send its gps location during regular intervals to hq or is that not a problem.

If I get these questions answered I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you find your answer, please mark the response as answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Pepper does not need internet connection to work with the basic package (basic channel https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/channels/). It will need internet connection for updating its system, the basic channel and in case you create an app that needs internet connection.
2. Create a network just for the Pepper and no one should know its credentials but you. Otherwise anyone within this network can connect to the robot just knowing its IP (the robot tells it after pressing the button behind its tablet) and do whatever he wants.
3. As far I know Pepper does not have GPS. I am experimenting with the ALNavigation and ALExploration and those two modules does not use GPS. They would work much better with GPS signal I guess.